# Avoiding the "Two event loops are trying to receive() on one channel layer at once!" error with Django Channels

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-channels

**In short:** I am trying to make Django-channels consumers communicate with a separate logic thread.

Regardless of what I ask below, there might be a better-suited option I need to consider besides Django-Channels. My goals are:

- I want to start logic thread **programmatically**, this is why Django-Channels worker threads do not really work for me.
- I want the logic thread to be able to send data to consumers
- I want consumers to be able to send data to the logic thread
- I do not want to handle game logic in a (for example) "host" consumer, as the game will crash if the host has to reconnect their websocket

Longer version: Let's say I am trying to make a simple game on a website, which uses websockets to communicate between the front- and backend. using Django Channels, this could be very easily set up.

However, when I need to handle game logic, I want to compute it in some central thread that does not cease whenever a client disconnects. I have found that you can communicate with consumers from some arbitrary thread from outside the consumer scope [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers). However, this has an issue:

- The game logic can send information to clients easily, but clients cannot send information back.
- If we were to use a RESTful API for clients to send information to the game logic thread, it would be slow, and we cannot make use of `consumer.disconnect()` to cleanly handle client disconnects.
- When trying to use `async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.receive)(...)` in the game logic thread, it results in the following error: `Two event loops are trying to receive() on one channel layer at once!` It is obvious that the `RedisChannelLayer` does not enjoy a separate thread listening for events.

I think therefore I need to find another way to somehow send information from a consumer to some other thread. In other words, in the following code snippet:

```
class GameClientConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def connect(self):
    # Accept the websocket connection.
    self.accept()

def receive_json(self, content=None, **kwargs):
    # Handle player input
    send_information_to_another_thread(data)
```

I need to find what `send_information_to_another_thread(data)` would look like. Is this even possible? Alternatively, I would like to find out how I could somehow `receive()` events from the channel layer from an arbitrary thread.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, it seems you need 2 things:

1. Send a message to the channel layer from outside the consumer. This you already found in the docs as you stated.
2. Send a  message from the consumer to another thread or block of code. The consumer code is just like any other Python code so you can call an arbitrary function from it. Of course, you should take care not to block the event loop and so should allocate heavy logic outside the consumer to another process or thread. You can put that outside logic in a celery task for example if it is heavy and simply call the task just like any other celery task. Essentially:

   ```
   def receive_json(self, content=None, **kwargs):
       # Handle player input
       celery_task.delay(**kwargs)
   ```

In that way, the task runs each time you receive a new message. If you have many of such tasks, you can fire a Django signal on receiving a new message instead and the handlers can then decide how to handle it (fire a celery task, run a small logic and return, send back some message to the consumer, etc)

You do not need to call the receive function through the channel layer. Instead, push messages from the receive function to the services that need them.